# How to know that the application has finished processing file?

Tags: assembly, binary, reverse-engineering, fuzzing

I am trying to automate the instrumentation which i am doing in the application, but the problem is i am dealing with applications which do not exits by itself after processing. For example take any pdfviewer/reader, If i open a file the file is displayed and i can see that the application has processed the file.

By processing of file by the application, what i mean is that file has been displayed successfully by the application.

Application can be any GUI pdf viewer for ex adobe reader, xpdf, foxitreader or any image viewer for ex gpicview, etc. File formats can be of any type not any specific file format.

Also i don't have the source code of an application, i am dealing with binary of the application.

But while automating the process, i want to know when the application has processed the file. What i can initially think is there would be some basic blocks which says that after it is executed it has finished processing the file and exit my instrumentation when the particular basic block has executed.

But the problem here is how to identify that basic block ?

Comment: I thought for large pdf files the displaying is using only partial file read, streaming in rest of data as needed when the user scrolls down... So it's not finished with the file, until the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest and most reliable thing that you can do automatically for black-box executables is to **look at their CPU usage**.  When they're done loading, all their threads should be (mostly) idle, maybe waking up occasionally if they wait for events with a non-infinite timeout.  (And from miscellaneous GUI events like mouse movement).

Make sure you wait long enough to detect the difference between blocked on disk I/O vs. blocked waiting for user input.  (On Unix-like OSes, this is the difference between Disk-sleep and Sleep, as shown by `D` vs. `S` in stuff like `top`'s process list.)

If you don't want to rely on the OS to detect disk-sleep vs. regular sleep, just wait a few times longer than the maximum disk I/O request service time (~= a few times disk latency, lower if the process under test is the only process doing I/O).  If the black-box process hasn't used any CPU time in that interval, you can assume it's done loading and is displaying the file on screen.

Of course, as @Ped7g points out, it may not have parsed the entire file.  It may load it lazily, on-demand, as the user scrolls through a large PDF for example.  Watching CPU time should be a reasonable way to detect when a process has finished updating after programmatically sending it a page-down command.

I think you should be able to get good reliable results from this.  You might need a heuristic that considers multiple inputs, like system I/O performance or outstanding disk-IO requests, if you want to reliably decide that a process is done loading without waiting as long as the worst-possible case.

---

As discussed in comments, **looking for the process to reach EOF on a file descriptor is not reliable for this purpose** (it might mmap it).  I'll leave this here in case it's interesting or useful for anyone, but for your use you might want to ignore this entirely.  At best, you might use this as an input to your heuristic for deciding when a process is done loading.

On most OSes, there are some facilities for processes to trace other processes.  On Linux, the main one is the ptrace API.  Commands like `strace` use it to trace system calls.  I believe Windows has something similar, and I assume OS X does, too.

So you can look for the open() system call on the PDF to find the right fd, then look for mmap, read(), and close() system calls on it.  If read() returns 0, it's at EOF.  If it's closed without mmap, the process is done with it (unless it opens it again, or used dup() or dup2() for some reason).

You could parse strace's text output, or use the ptrace API yourself.

---

Alternatively, on Linux you can look at the file position in `/proc/<PID>/fdinfo/<FD>`.  Other OSes probably have similar facilities for seeing the file position of open file descriptors / file handles.

For example, I happen to have `evince` open displaying a PDF.  In `/proc/

```
$ ll /proc/4241/fd
...
lr-x------ 1 peter peter 64 Oct 21 06:43 14 -> /f/p/docs/agner_fog.microarchitecture.pdf    # is anyone really surprised this is the PDF I had open?  :P
...
$ ls -lL /proc/4241/fd/14       # follow the symlink to see the file size
-rw-rw-r-- 1 peter peter 2078709 Feb  4  2016 /proc/4241/fd/14

$ m /proc/4241/fdinfo/14        # alias for less
pos:    2078709
flags:  0100000
mnt_id: 49
```

This confirms my guess the evince will have the file position at EOF when it's done reading the file.  You should probably wait several milliseconds and check again, in case the software under test loops over the file again.

Comment: Is it necessary that close or EOF will indicate that application has finished processing, Suppose i have read the file in a buffer and then to display the data i am using that buffer. By processing of file i do not mean that file has been read completely. What i mean is that it has been displayed successfully.

Comment: @user2823667: Yeah, that's a good point.  Probably a combination of that and waiting for it to stop using CPU time are your best bet.  Just wait until it has read the file and hasn't used any significant amount of CPU time for ~40ms or something, depending on your disk I/O latency.  (Avoid false positives when it's waiting on I/O).

Comment: @user2823667: If you can track whether any of its threads used up their entire timeslice, vs. whether they just woke up to handle a GUI event and went back to sleep right away, that would be the thing to look for, I think.

Comment: What if the application mmaps the file, closes it, and only then process it? You cannot (easily) check what accesses to the file an application does when it's just a part of its address space.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh: Good point, watching the file descriptor is not reliable in general.  Waiting for the process's CPU usage to go to near-zero for longer than a few times your disk I/O latency should always work.  If you want to write more code to maybe detect with more certainty in *some* cases (and thus not wait quite as long to make sure the process is now idle), you could use strace to detect that the process has closed the file without mmapping it.  But I think looking at the process's CPU usage is actually the best bet.  I'm going to edit my answer to put that as the first suggestion.